A Prophet’s Garment of Hair
In reference to Zechariah 13:4,

And on that day every prophet who prophesies will be ashamed of his
vision, and he will not put on a hairy cloak in order to deceive.

I noticed it connects to 2 Kings 1:8, Matthew 3:4 and Hebrews 11:37.

2 Kings 1:8 - They answered him, “He wore a garment of hair, with a
belt of leather about his waist.” And he said, “It is Elijah the
Tishbite.”
Matt 3:4 - John wore a garment of camel’s hair, with a leather belt
around his waist. His food was locusts and wild honey.
Heb 11:37 - They were stoned, they were sawed in two, they were put to
death by the sword. They went around in sheepskins and goatskins,
destitute, oppressed, and mistreated.

My question is does the prophet’s garment of hair connect to Genesis 3:21 in anyway?

And the LORD God made garments of skin for Adam and his wife, and He
clothed them.


Please could you quote the texts you are referring to. You are leaving your readership to do the research. Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Hairy garments are a simple indication of poverty.  That is all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Camel hair is an allusion to regeneration, the word for camel and the word for baby being Hebrew homonyms. A baby drinks and drinks from its mother ; a camel drinks and drinks. storing the water. The waterpots are filled to the brim, then they become wine. These are spiritual allusions to be noticed. But many will dispute and criticise and copy and paste, for these are spiritial interpretations, not mechanical literacies.

Not likely.
The passage in Zachariah 13:4 refers to the Day of the LORD and Israel's coming salvation. It’s more likely hinting or referencing when Jacob deceived his old-in-age and nearly blind father, Issac, by mimicking the physical feel of his brother Esau, who was hairy and heir to all of Issac’s land and goods.
In Jacob tangibly feeling like Esau to his blind father Issac (Gen 27:11), Jacob deceitfully took from Issac Esau’s firstborn inheritance rights  (Esau renounced his birthright to Jacob for a bowl of soup, but that’s a whole ‘nother conversation). Read the whole story in Gen 27.
Zachariah prophesies that the false prophets who will arise on the Day of Salvation will be seen for what they are and will be killed by their mother and father if they speak another deceptive word on behalf of the LORD Almighty (Zac 13:3).
Simeon Peter references these false prophets in 2 Peter 2:1,3

1 But false prophets also arose among the people, just as there will be false teachers among you, who will secretly bring in destructive heresies, even denying the Master who bought them, bringing upon themselves swift destruction.
3 …Their condemnation from long ago is not idle, and their destruction is not asleep.

The passage in Gen 3:21 speaks of skin being clothing because of The Fall, Adam and Eve (and all humanity forward) understood and perceived their nakedness.
At first Adam and Eve, much like the rest of human history, tried to cover up their own sin with leaves. Yet, only God could provide provisions of atonement for their sins.
And so God covered them with the flesh of a once-alive, now-dead animal’s body - this covering of nakedness paid with the cost of life was the first foreshadowing of the price the Sinless Lamb, Jesus, would pay to bring reconciliation to humanity.
